# Installing Twisted: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python-3.x, windows, twisted, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I'm trying to install `channels` on a Windows 10 box. I keep getting the following error:

```
$ pip install --user channels
... Stuff here
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\uscs\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tgzm6i1z\\twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\uscs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d1l_mx2x\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\uscs\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tgzm6i1z\twisted\
```

Tons of searching SO and other places on the Internet have left me no closer to the answer. Here's what I've tried:

1. Installed VS build tools. Nearly everything I found on this topic is outdated and about VS 2015, so I'm flying a bit blind here. The error message isn't nice enough to say *which* of the myriad tools I need, so here's what I've installed:

   - Visual Studio build tools 2019

     1. C++ build tools
     2. MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.20)
     3. Windows 10 SDK
     4. C++ CMake tools for Windows
     5. Testing tools core features - Build Tools
   - Visual Studio build tools 2017

     1. Visual C++ build tools core features
     2. VC++ 2017 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools
     3. Other stuff the same as above
2. In other reading, I've read that sometimes it's necessary to upgrade `setuptools`, so I've done that.
3. I've rebooted for good measure.

None of the above has had any effect whatsoever, despite what answers to other questions have said.

What's wrong? I'm primarily a Linux user, so Windows issues tend to stump me.